# Is there any way to have SQLite output in color?

Tags: sqlite, colors, terminal

I'm curious if `sqlite3` has the potential to output text in colors to make it easier to read in Terminal? I didn't see anything in the documentation so I'm guessing it does not, unless there is an extension for it or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line shell outputs the in-memory database warning in bold:

`$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.19.0 2017-03-30 17:13:37
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.`                           ⇦ bold
`Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>`

This is done with VT100 escape sequences:

```c
static void printBold(const char *zText){
  printf("\033[1m%s\033[0m", zText);
}
```

So you could change your queries to add such escape sequences to the output, e.g., `␛[31m` for red:

```
SELECT x, char(27)||'[31m' || y || char(27)||'[0m' AS y_red
FROM (SELECT 'abc' AS x, 123 AS y);
```

```perl
abc|123
```